# R Question - Trying to use separate to split data with a non-constant delimiter

Tags: r, delimiter, tidyr

One of the variables is participant age groups, an example of one of the records is shown below,

```
0::Adult 18+||1:: Adult 18+||2::Adult 18+||3::Child 0-11
```

How do you best split this out so that it will give Adult 18 + with the result of 3 and Child 0-11 with 1?

I tried using separate, but as the delimiter is not constant, it was omitting a lot of the records. Any suggestions would be helpful, thank you! As this is my first post, let me know if I need to add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
library(magrittr)

vals <- "0::Adult 18+||1:: Adult 18+||2::Adult 18+||3::Child 0-11"
strsplit(gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]]","", vals), "\\s+") %>% as.data.frame() %>% table()

Adult Child 
    3     1
```

Comment: Thank you mysteRious! Is the vals where I place Adult or Child or the column name?

Comment: I just saved the string you provided as a string called vals (see edited answer above). You may need to adapt it if you are reading (for example) rows from a data frame. Edit your question if you need that. If this solution works for you, remember to click the button that says it provided you an answer that worked for you. Thanks :)