# R Question - Non-Constant Delimiter and tying it back into the data frame

Tags: r, string, dplyr, delimiter, tidyr

This is a follow-up question from another question,
[R Question - Trying to use separate to split data with a non-constant delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58677011/r-question-trying-to-use-separate-to-split-data-with-a-non-constant-delimiter)

Only afterward did I realize that I had more questions, please bear with me, thank you!

As an example for the participation_age_group, I would like to split it out into Adult, Teens, and Child so that each incident gives the count of each age group participant. I am trying to do the same with age and gender and then tie it back to the overall dataset to make predictions. Let me know if you need more detail.

```
dput(head(x[, c(1, 3)]))    structure(list(incident=c(1,2),age_group= c("0::Adult 18+", "0::Adult 18+||1::Adult 18+"), participant_gender = c("0::Female","0::Male||1::Male")),.Names = c("incident","participant_age_group","participant_gender"),row.names = c(NA, 2L), class = "data.frame")
```

More data if needed, 
[Sample Data from the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw8ER.png)

I tried using the below, but it just gives one massive vector.

strings <- c("Child 0-11","Teen 12-17","Adult 18+")

x <- str_count(strings,x$participant_age_group)

Desired Outcome

```
Incident Child Teen Adult Female Male
   1       0    0    1      1     0
   2       0    0    2      0     2
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` instead of screenshots. Can you also show the expected output for the given example ?

Comment: I will make sure to use dput next time. Is it possible to add dput into a response?                                                             Child Teen Adult
  0     0      1
  0     0      2

Comment: Add result of `dput` and expected output in the original post by editing the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample based on your image. I do not know how many age group you have. If you have a lot, you gotta do something different. But here you have three categories. I created a vector with them. I used `stri_count()` using the vector in a loop with sapply(). I applied the same procedure to the gender variable as well. In the end, I combined the two results with `bind_cols()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

so <- tibble(id = 1:4,
             participant_age_group = c("0::Adult 18+", 
                                       NA,
                                       "0::Child 0-11||1::Teen 12-17",
                                       "0::Adult 18+||1::Adult 18+"),
             participant_gender = c("0::Female",
                                    NA,
                                    "0::Female||1::Female",
                                    "0::Male||1::Female"))

# Create a vector with the three target categories.
category <- c("Child 0-11", "Teen 12-17", "Adult 18+")
gender <- c("Female",  "Male")

sapply(category,function(x){
  stri_count_regex(so$participant_age_group, x)
}) %>% 
as_tibble -> result1

sapply(gender,function(x){
stri_count_regex(so$participant_gender, x)
}) %>% 
as_tibble -> result2

bind_cols(result1, result2)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  `Child 0-11` `Teen 12-17` `Adult 18+` Female  Male
#         <int>        <int>       <int>  <int> <int>
#1            0            0           1      1     0
#2           NA           NA          NA     NA    NA
#3            1            1           0      2     0
#4            0            0           2      1     1
```

Comment: Thank you, how would I add this back to the bigger data frame?

Comment: @schenss I realized that you now added a sample data. If you use that, you can change the column name in stri_count_regex() to another. You also create another vector contain gender levels and use that in sapply(). You can combine the two results with bind_cols().

Comment: @jazzuro - Thank you, that code is exactly what I needed! What does the "x" represent? When I tried combining with bind_cols, it gave me an error message that the argument must have names, what would cause that?

Comment: @schenss I updated my answer. I hope this clears up your mind.